# FB.api and jquery ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need help with calling FB.api function when jquery ajax() call returns with success. The alert showing facebook name works only in Chrome. Nothing to do with Firefox and IE8. alert(data) is ok and the window reload also. But FB.api no.  Thanks very much for your help:

```
function fb_login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      //alert('login');
      if (response.authResponse) {


$.ajax({
    url: 'fb_login.asp',
    data: '',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    timeout: 10000,
    error: function(){
        alert('Error login Facebook');
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        // do something with xml

        FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
            alert(resp.name);
        });        

        window.location.reload();
        //alert('ok');
    }
});  



      }


    }, {scope:'email,publish_stream'});

}
```

Comment: *"This code works only in Chrome. Nothing to do with Firefox and IE8."* Huh? Do you mean it doesn't work in Firefox and IE8? If so, **how** does it not work? What result do you see? What result do you *expect* to see? What do you see when you walk through with a proper debugger (both Firefox and IE8 have them), set breakpoints, inspect variables, etc.?

Comment: Hi T.J. I expect to see the alert: alert(resp.name); In Chrome the alert with my fb name is shown. In Firefox and IE no alert is shown. Yesterday I tried to inspect with Firebug but I'm new to debugging html pages and as now I'm lost. The alert(data) is working and the window reload is working. Only FB.api isn't working

Comment: `@bepi`: Best to add that to the question using the "edit" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to FB.api is asynchronous so the page reloads before the callback function is executed. Try this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
    alert(resp.name);
    window.location.reload();
    alert('ok');
});
```